# TDirectoryWatch not firing first time

Tags: delphi, shell

I have a small application that is used to process some files made in another program.
I use an older component by Angus Johnson called `TDirectoryWatch`

On my FormCreate I have the following code

```
  DirectoryWatch := TDirectoryWatch.Create(self);
  DirectoryWatch.OnChange := FileAction;
  DirectoryWatch.Directory := Folders.Path(dirInput);
  DirectoryWatch.Active := True;
```

If the program is started and there is put a new file in the directory everything fires and runs OK.
But if there is a file in the directory when the program is started nothing happens even if I make a call to FileAction(nil);

`FileAction` is the name of the procedure that handles the files

I have a call to FileAction from a popupmenu and that handles the files in the directory

So my question is: how to make sure that existing files are handled at program start?

Or is there a better way to handle this problem.

Added code for FileAction

```
procedure TfrmMain.FileAction(Sender: TObject);
var
  MailFile: string;
  MailInfo: TMailInfo;
  ListAttachments: TstringList;
  i: integer;
  MailBody: string;
begin
  for MailFile in TDirectory.GetFiles(Folders.Path(dirInput), CheckType) do
    begin
      if FileExists(MailFile) then
        begin
          MailInfo := TMailInfo.Create(MailFile);
          try
            if FileProcessing = False then
              begin
                Logfile.Event('Behandler fil: ' + MailFile);
                FileProcessing            := True;
                MailBody                  := '';
                Settings.Load;
                MailInfo.Load;
                Settings.Mail.Signature   := '';
                Settings.Mail.Subject     := MailInfo.Subject;
                ListAttachments           := TStringList.Create;
                ListAttachments.Clear;
                for i := 1 to MaxEntries do
                  begin
                    if (MailInfo.Attachment[i] <> '') and (FileExists(MailInfo.Attachment[i])) then
                      ListAttachments.Add(MailInfo.Attachment[i]);
                  end;
                for i := 1 to MaxEntries do
                  begin
                    MailBody := MailBody + MailInfo.MailBody[i];
                  end;
                try
                  if MailBody <> '' then
                    begin
                      if MailInfo.SenderBcc then
                        Mailing.Send(MailInfo.SenderMail, MailInfo.Recipient, MailInfo.SenderMail, MailInfo.Subject, MailBody, ListAttachments, True)
                      else
                        Mailing.Send(MailInfo.SenderMail, MailInfo.Recipient, MailInfo.Subject, MailBody, ListAttachments, True);
                    end;
                finally
                  ListAttachments.Free;
                end;
                FileProcessing := False;
                DeleteFile(MailFile);
              end;
          finally
            MailInfo.Free;
          end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Include the code in your `FileAction` that's seems to be where the problem is.

Comment: I don't see what the implementation of `FileAction` has to do with the behavior of the component. If you think there's a problem with your code, then you need to give some idea of what that is. You can't expect others to debug your program for you when you haven't described what debugging you've already done. What behavior do you observe, and what did you expect instead? Not that it's relevant to *this* question, though.

Comment: As I say my problem is that files are not being processed at program start but when program is running and files are added to the 'watch dir' the processing starts and all files are processed OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The component doesn't notify about changes when your program starts up because at the time your program starts, there haven't been any changes yet.

Your policy appears to be that at the time your program starts up, all existing files are to be considered "new" or "newly changed," so your approach of manually calling the change-notification handler is correct.

The only thing the component does when it detects a change is to call the change-notification handler. If you explicitly call that function, and yet you still observe that "nothing happens," then there are more deep-seated problems in your program that you need to debug; it's not an issue with the component or with the basic approach described here.

Comment: I think that the problem is that I call FileAction from the FormShow event and that doesn't gets executed - might have to do with that fact that the program is just running in systray 
Moving the call to FileAction to FormCreate looks like it solves my problem for the time being

Comment: I see. Your idea to manually call the function at program start was correct. The problem is that the call site you chose *doesn't actually run* at program start. That's the deep-seated problem I referred to. Glad you found it.